# Django authentication works on Chrome, but not on Firefox

Tags: django, google-chrome, python-2.7, firefox, django-authentication

I'm having a problem where Django's login is working okay on Chrome but not on Firefox: when trying to login to a restricted portion of the site on Firefox, it simply loops back again and again to the login page; furthermore, no error message appears on the log regarding that.
Interestingly, the error doesn't happen when the server is on the local machine.

Does someone have a general idea of what could be causing that strange behavior?

I'm using Django 1.6 on Python 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this isn't much of an answer, but a linking to other similar problems. Because I don't have rep, all I can do is leave an answer.

A issue like this was encountered in 2012 but was never conclusively answered:
[Django session doesn't work in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626783/django-session-doesnt-work-in-firefox)

A similar question where the user could login via local server but not remote firefox was encoutered:
[Unable log in to the django admin page with a valid username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894765/unable-log-in-to-the-django-admin-page-with-a-valid-username-and-password)

The second was very well documented and had an accepted answer that was well liked.

Recommendations:

1. If you are not using https make sure you have this setting SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False.
2. If you are using a database backed, Check if the session is actually being created in the django_sessions table .
3. If you are using a cached backed, check that SESSION_ENGINE is django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache *and* that CACHE_BACKEND is properly configured.

Comment: In my case, emptying the session table and cleaning up the domain cookies seemed to solve the problem, though I still haven't found the exact cause of the problem.